# Activity don't show xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

Here is `ss_birth.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/SSB_Tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:text="@string/SSB_Tv"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/SSB_Btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="@string/SSB_Btn"
        android:textSize="23sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And `SSBirthActivity.java`:

```
package ru.abcdefg.abcd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SSBirthActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ss_birth);
    }
}
```

And here is an activity. From it I want to start `SSBirthActivity`:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

String TAG = "Days";

int firstTimeCheck = 0; // 0 = 1st time; 1 = not 1st time

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.w(TAG, "--- MenuActivity ---");

    Log.i(TAG, "Starting first time check");
    firstTimeCheck = 0; // TEST OPTION [Make first time]
    if (firstTimeCheck == 0) {
        Log.w(TAG, "First time. Starting SSBirthActivity");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SSBirthActivity.class);
        firstTimeCheck = 1;

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ru.abcdefg.abcd"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>
    <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
            android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="MenuActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:launchMode="standard"
                  android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SSBirthActivity" android:label="Введите д/р"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But when this activity starts there is just a white screen.

By the way, when this activity starts, title changing. So activity starts, but shows nothing. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
SergaRUS

Comment: Can you post your `AndroidManifest.xml`? Your `LinearLayout` is not closed properly, but that is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Emmanuel I've added `AndroidManifest` to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` you are making `MenuActivity` your `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER` `Activity`. This is interpreted by the system as the entry point to your app. If you want `SSBirthActivity` to be your entry point change the `<intent-filter>` on it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ru.abcdefg.abcd"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>
    <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
            android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="MenuActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:launchMode="standard"
                  android:enabled="true">              
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SSBirthActivity" android:label="Введите д/р">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you still want `MenuActivty` to be the entry point, you can send an `Intent` from it to `SSBirthActivity` to start it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SSBirthActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Look at my updated version of your `AndroidManifest.xml`. I made `SSBirthActivity` the entry point of your app by switching the `<intent-filter>` from `MenuActivity`.

Comment: Look throw my update. I want to start `SSBirthActivity` from `MainActivity`

Comment: Then you should use an explicit `Intent`. See my updated answer.

Comment: But it were there) Look throw my question one more time) @emmanuel

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: In my questoin with title `And here is an activity. From it I want to start SSBirthActivity:` there is an activity where I have used `Intent`. Then my `SSBirthActivity` starts, but shows the wite screen (I've understood that cause of the title changing). And I want to know "Why it shows the wite screen?". Get it?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested your layout. It works. I might be a bug from formatting. Try auto formatting. Do you know how it works?

Do you have a end tag for your LinearLayout?

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/SSB_Tv"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
>     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>     android:text="abc"
>     android:textSize="25sp" />
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/SSB_Btn"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
>     android:text="def"
>     android:textSize="23sp" />
> ```

If that does not help, please post your manifest.

Best regards
Vince

**EDIT:**

Try to use this in your manifest instead. This will start your second Activity at first. There is nothing wrong with your layout. Your question belongs to another problem.

```
 <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="MenuActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="standard" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ru.abcdefg.abcd.SSBirthActivity"
            android:label="Введите д/р" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. His problem is not with his layout files.

Comment: How is this different than my answer? What else does it provide?

Comment: Because you edited your answer, too. I did not see your update in time. What's wrong? Do you feel offended? I just want to help, man.

Comment: I do not feel offended. The point is that there is no need to repeat the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can start Activity from inside an other with an Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SSBirthActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Just put this Code in the Main Activity and it will work.
Oh i did not see the other Post cause he was posted while ive created mine.